# Convert object to IEnumerable in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, casting

I'm writting generic validate function. It will use reflection to navigate through properties of an object and validate them. But I got a problem with collection property. I can determine if it's an `array` or `generic` but can not cast it in order to loop throught its entities.

```
private static bool Validate(object model)
{
    if (model.GetType().IsGenericType || model.GetType().IsArray)
    {
        //I want to convert model to IEnumerable here in order to loop throught it
        //It seems that .NET 2.0 doesn't allow me to cast by using
        IEnumerable lst = model as IEnumerable;
        //or
        IEnumerable lst = (IEnumerable) model;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Silly me, turned out that using

```
IEnumerable lst = model as IEnumerable;
```

work perfectly. The problem I got is that by switching from .NET 4.0 to .NET 2.0, I stuck in a conclusion that .NET 2.0 doesn't support direct cast to `IEnumerable` without provide a specific type and I haven't noticed that `System.Collection` hasn't been imported. I feel like an idiot now.

P/S: sorry you guys for the waste of time

Comment: Please give a short but complete example of where you think it *should* work but doesn't. It should be absolutely fine.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable lst = model as IEnumerable;
if(lst != null)
{
    //loop
}
```

This should work if the model implements `IEnumerable`.

The following would throw an invalid cast exception:

```
IEnumerable lst = (IEnumerable) model;
```